# C# Reading excel file ignores 1st row

Tags: c#, excel, dataset, oledb

I'm using OLEDB for reading `Excel` file. After reading I'm saving it into `DataSet` for future usages.

The folowing code works just nice, but always **ignores** the first row of `Excel` file.
How could this be fixed?
Please, just ignore comments and exception's texts.
There's the screens of result(I'm displaying resulted `DatatSet`'s first `DataTable` to `DevExpress` `GridView`.
[image: Screens]

```
public static class ExcelHelperFasad
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Прочитать excel'евский файл и вернуть DataSet с заполненными DataTable'ами для каждой страницы.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filename">Имя файла.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static DataSet OpenExcelFile(string filename)
    {
        if (File.Exists(filename) == false)
            throw new MyException("Файл не существует : " + filename);

        var dataTables = new List<DataTable>();

        var sheets = ListSheetInExcel(filename);

        if (sheets.Count == 0)
            throw new MyException("В Excel файле не найдено ни одной страницы. Проверьте файл на наличие страниц : " + filename);

        foreach (var sheet in sheets)
        {
            var dataTable = LoadWorksheetInDataTable(filename, sheet);

            dataTables.Add(dataTable);
        }

        var dataSet = new DataSet(Path.GetFileName(filename));

        foreach (var dataTable in dataTables)
            dataSet.Tables.Add(dataTable);

        return dataSet;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="fileName"></param>
    /// <param name="sheetName"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static DataTable LoadWorksheetInDataTable(string fileName, string sheetName)
    {
        var sheetData = new DataTable(sheetName);
        using (var conn = ReturnConnection(fileName))
        {
            conn.Open();
            // retrieve the data using data adapter
            var sheetAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [" + sheetName + "]", conn);
            sheetAdapter.Fill(sheetData);
        }
        return sheetData;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// OLEDB коннекшон.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="fileName"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static OleDbConnection ReturnConnection(string fileName)
    {
        return new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + fileName + "; Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5;Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;\"");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Список страниц.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filePath"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static List<string> ListSheetInExcel(string filePath)
    {
        var sbConnection = new OleDbConnectionStringBuilder();
        var strExtendedProperties = string.Empty;
        sbConnection.DataSource = filePath;
        if (Path.GetExtension(filePath).Equals(".xls"))//for 97-03 Excel file
        {
            sbConnection.Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0";
            strExtendedProperties = "Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1";//HDR=ColumnHeader,IMEX=InterMixed
        }
        else if (Path.GetExtension(filePath).Equals(".xlsx"))  //for 2007 Excel file
        {
            sbConnection.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0";
            strExtendedProperties = "Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1";
        }
        else
            throw new MyException("Ошибка чтения Excel файла. Необходимо сконвертировать Ваш файл в \".xlsx\" или \".xls\" формат.");

        sbConnection.Add("Extended Properties", strExtendedProperties);
        var listSheet = new List<string>();
        using (var conn = new OleDbConnection(sbConnection.ToString()))
        {
            conn.Open();
            var dtSheet = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
            foreach (DataRow drSheet in dtSheet.Rows)
            {
                if (drSheet["TABLE_NAME"].ToString().Contains("$"))//checks whether row contains '_xlnm#_FilterDatabase' or sheet name(i.e. sheet name always ends with $ sign)
                    listSheet.Add(drSheet["TABLE_NAME"].ToString());
            }
        }
        return listSheet;
    }
}
```

Comment: HDR=1 is the issue, make it HDR=0 - according to the comments on the code the code is assuming a HEADER row, that would be a row that has headings before the data - your data doesnt have this, and thats why thefirst row is being skipped

Comment: @user230910 changed. Now it displays 1st column name from 1st row of excel file.

Comment: There is no need to check the file extension and use the older provider and a different extended properties. The Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider with Excel 12.0 an Extended Property will open both file types just fine. You should avoid using the Jet provider

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change "HDR" to "No" in strExtendedProperties:

```
    if (Path.GetExtension(filePath).Equals(".xls"))//for 97-03 Excel file
    {
        sbConnection.Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0";
        strExtendedProperties = "Excel 8.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1";//HDR=ColumnHeader,IMEX=InterMixed
    }
    else if (Path.GetExtension(filePath).Equals(".xlsx"))  //for 2007 Excel file
    {
        sbConnection.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0";
        strExtendedProperties = "Excel 12.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1";
    }
    else
        throw new MyException("Ошибка чтения Excel файла. Необходимо сконвертировать Ваш файл в \".xlsx\" или \".xls\" формат.");
```

Otherwise it will always interpret first row as column names.

Comment: Now it displays 1st column name from 1st row of excel file.

Comment: Maybe your GridView is not set to autogenerate columns?

Answer (score 0):

HDR=1 is the issue, make it HDR=0 - according to the comments on the code the code is assuming a HEADER row, that would be a row that has headings before the data - your data doesnt have this, and thats why thefirst row is being skipped

Comment: Now it displays 1st column name from 1st row of excel file.

Comment: the screenshot you have above doesnt show any column names?

Comment: it does, u can see it(columns are grey, rows are white).